# Import in chain in Python: import from outside two dependent files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

**Problem**

I struggle to find a nice way to import modules in chain when your second import is from outside the folder. More clearly, here is my folder organisation:

```
main/                          
    __init__.py              
    a/                  
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
    b/                  
        __init__.py
        stuff.py
```

In `stuff.py` -- typically a big piece of code -- I want to do something like this:

`from a.foo import thing`

but in `foo.py` -- typically some kind of library -- I have already something like this:

`from bar import other_thing`

When I run `stuff.py`, I have an import error saying that `foo.py` does not know the module `bar`. Of course, when I run `foo.py` alone, I have no error.

**Possible solutions so far**

A simple workaround is to put:

`from a.bar import other_thing`

instead in `foo.py`. But it feels strange to have to specify the module `a` since both files live in the same folder. When you develop something in `foo.py`, you should not have to care about this.

I can also add something like:

`sys.path.insert(1, '../a')`

in `stuff.py`. But in this case in `stuff.py` I can completely ignore the module structure and just import:

`from foo import thing`

which does not feel right either.

This is purely a question of style, but I am sure that there is a nice solution for this, probably using the `__init__.py` files. I can't find it though. Any idea?

I am using Python 3.4 by the way

Comment: From the `main` directory, try to run `python -m b.stuff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use package relative imports in `foo.py`.

```
from .bar import other_thing
```

See [Intra-Package References](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) for details.

Note that if you run `stuff.py` directly, it is a top-level script (`__main__`) and is not a member of the package. If some other module imports `b.stuff`, you get a different copy. Personally, I put top-level scripts in a different `bin` directory so they are not mistaken for package modules.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Regarding your other comment, I do the same I think. In theory no file should import from stuff (even though it is not called bin per se).